# How to find push / common commits in git history?

Tags: git, version-control

Our application processes data and we are trying to find a state of an application, where data started to be processed incorrectly. We know, that data processing was ran by person A while commits were made by persons B, C, D, ... We are using git with multiple local and single remote repository.

Obviously, person A was unable to run code in a version, which was not yet pushed to global repository. So there is no sense to check between commits made by person B util he did a push.

Is it possible to find commits or states of the code between such pushes in git history?

Comment: Between pushes? Commits don't contain information about when they were pushed.

Comment: @evolutionxbox pity!

Comment: If you use a tool like github, you could find the commit refs associated with each push, and then compare them?

Comment: I am using bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried `git blame` - Show what revision and author last modified each line of a file

You can use `git blame -l <filename>` to get the SHA1 hash from when the line was changed.

Comment: I think I need something opposite. I don't know the file, but I know datetime of a report.

Comment: are you looking for this.  git log --since=jun9 --until=jun10 --author=Bhanu